# iOS Team Provisioning. Xcode does not offer our teams profile as an option. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I know we all have our own personal hell stories of setting up iOS provisioning. Deep breath. Ok.

Our team of three has a team provisioning profile setup. Check. It appears in the Xcode organizer. Check. Now I want to actually use this profile for a project. But the set of provisioning profiles offered in the dropdown list does not include our teams profile as one of the options. It does offer others (I have more then one Apple dev id). My other teammates have the identical problem. We all have an 'iOS Team Provision Profile' created on the same date but with differing identifying numbers.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the developer certificate that lives in the keychain (It's in Keychain Access application). Does it exist? Great! Does it have an arrow that, when you click on it, unfolds and shows your name? Yes? Great!

If neither of those things are not true, then go to provisioning portal and go through that certification process again (see the site for detailed directions).

If the cert isn't the issue, check the appID and what's listed under the bundle identifier in info.plist. If that's not exactly right, it won't work.

Good luck!

Comment: Everything you describe exists. The problem is that each of us has a profile that calls itself team provisioning profile but the friggin' number is different for each of us and *not* the number of the profile in the Apple portal. Sigh.

Comment: Do any of the team member's work? If so, I would export that certificate to the other members who will be able to use it.  If not, then start from scratch with one member and then export. 

Good luck…